# JSLint "document.write can be a form of eval" - How is this so?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've come across this message in JSLint...

> document.write can be a form of eval.

and was wondering exactly how so?

The [JSLint instructions](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) page states:

> The eval function...provide access to the JavaScript
>   compiler. This is sometimes necessary,
>   but in most cases it indicates the
>   presence of extremely bad coding....

So, how does `document.write` "provide access to the JavaScript compiler" then?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15048239/798677

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What does your browser do with this?

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("evaled " + (1 + 2))</script>');
```

Comment: @Rocket: Seems I'm a little out of date, the `type` attribute is now preferred.  But deprecated or not, it works.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it works, but that's probably because browsers are ignoring the `language` attribute in the first place.

Comment: @Rocket: Is this the correct modern equivalent?  I only dabble in DHTML.

Comment: @Ben: Yup, that's correct.  :-)
In HTML5, the type isn't even needed JavaScript is assumed.

Comment: Back on topic - Think I understand. The `document.write` is itself writing out JavaScript which is then accessing the compiler. Condensing it down `document.write('<script>alert(1 + 2)</script>');` is therefore broadly equivalent to 
`alert(eval(1+2));`

Comment: @James: It's closer to `eval(alert(1+2))`.  `document.write` isn't just doing math, it's accessing browser objects, can define functions, etc.

Comment: So how do we get it past the Pedantic JS Lint?

var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', domain);
        document.write(iframe);

Comment: @WillHancock, It's not pedantic in this case. It is warning specifically about a potential vulnerability in your code that could enable, for instance, XSS attacks. Perhaps you know that, and know that your particular usage is safe. In which case you can disable the check for a specific line with `jshint ignore:[...]` comments (e.g. `// jshint ignore:line` at the end of your `document.write` line)