# Error Message: document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

When I try to run one of my JavaScript files on JSFiddle, I get the following error message:

> document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle.

How do I fix this issue?

**Note:** When I use external resources, it works fine. But I want to use the JavaScript panel for scripts.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/erh7m9og/1/

```
document.write = function (str) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);
}

document.write("¡hola mundo");
```

Answer (score 8):

its not any issue with your code. Its related to jsfiddle that it doesnt allow to run those code having `document.write`.

As an alternative you could use

```
console.log(x);
```

where ever you are having a

```
document.write(x);
```

and check up in the chrome inspector or firebug console for verifying result.

If you are more concerned about why `document.write` is blocked by jsfiddle, the below So posts may help to get a better understanding.

[Why am i receiving this jsfiddle error, document.write can be a form of eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048194/why-am-i-receiving-this-jsfiddle-error-document-write-can-be-a-form-of-eval)

[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

While testing the script, you could do this:

```
document.write = function(txt)
{
    console.log(txt);
}
document.write("hey");
```

And when you are satisfied, just take that part out

Answer (score 0):

You have `document.write` in your code, this breaks the result panel and the initialization of awesome.

Remove `document.write` from your code & it start working again

Comment: ^^^yes. `document.write` is not supported in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 
`document.body.innerHtml = "Hello";`