# Caching facebook and g+ js files, no errors but buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, caching, google-plus

Right now I load the facebook, twitter, google, pinterest, ... asynch by appending them into the DOM after the window load, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sm_l() {      
       ! function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
              js = d.createElement(s);
              js.id = id;
              js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
              js.async = true;
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }
      }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
      window.___gcfg = {
          lang: 'es'
      };
      (function() {
          var po = document.createElement('script');
          po.type = 'text/javascript';
          po.async = true;
          po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
      (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121495767915738";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      (function() {
          var po = document.createElement('script');
          po.type = 'text/javascript';
          po.async = true;
          po.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();

      $('#share_the_love').show();
      $('.social_media').slideDown();      
  }     
</script>
```

Thing is that it stills many requests that can't be cached with htaccess because those are external resources.

So I thought I'd cache them all in a single local .js file and use that one insted, like this:

```
<?php
function curl_file_get_contents($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);    //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);    //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);  //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);    //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $contents = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $contents;
}
$resoruces = array( 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121495767915738', 'https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js', 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' );

foreach($resoruces as $resource) {
    $result .= curl_file_get_contents($resource);
}
$result = file_put_contents('./js/cached/social.js', $result);
?>
```

Loading cached file instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sm_l() {
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script');
            po.type = 'text/javascript';
            po.async = true;
            po.src = '//funcook.com/js/cached/social.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
        $('#share_the_love').show();
        $('.social_media').slideDown();
    }       
</script>
```

Thing is that twitter buttons seem to work, but google+ and facebook are not,

The thing is that I am not getting errors in console, even getting the usual facebook log:

[image]

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4fms9u6/1/

Any idea what am I missing?

-EDIT-

Main reason:

[image]

Comment: I don't really see a point in caching these files on your server (not on the clients). What do you expect from doing this? Not clear to me...

Comment: Basically, get better results in the pagespeed test; also reduce http requests and being able to set expiration to these files

Comment: I highly doubt that this really has an effect. And, what happens if FB of G+ change the file contents? You won't recognize that IMHO. And why you would want to set an expiration of foreign resources is also not clear to me.

Comment: Well I would solve that b caching a fresh copy every x. Its just a matter optimising requests, specially for mobile devices, thanks!

Comment: If I press the button "TidyUp" in the jsfiddle it shows the message: "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle". That's a known issue in Jsfiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783834/error-msg-document-write-is-disallowed-in-jsfiddle-envioriment-and-might-break Maybe you should try the new Stackoverflow feature: code snippet.

Comment: @JohannEchavarria I don't know wich tool you mean, Do you have a link?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ga5xYYD.png

Comment: Hi, thanks! I didn't see it before! But its too much code in this case I guess, I get the max lenght error...

Answer (score 0):

try this code for social buttons:

```
function showSocialButtons() {
    var html =
    '<div id="social-buttons" class="fadeable fade">'
    + '<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://yourdomain.com" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" ></div>'
    + '<div class="g-plusone-frame"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="http://yourdomain.com"></div></div>'
    + '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://yourdomain.com" data-text="urbanAsk - The addicting game of helping people find things." data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>'            
    + '</div>';
    document.getElementById('viewport').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', html);

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121495767915738';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(script);

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    document.getElementById('social-buttons').appendChild(script);

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    document.getElementById('social-buttons').appendChild(script);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('social-buttons').removeAttribute('class');
}, 4000);};

showSocialButtons();
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dotnet/qnyuyk9q/

Comment: Hello! the thing is that I am trying to combine all those .js files and cache it locally, so I use that unique and with expiration cache. What you suggest are still externan resources without expiration cache.. thanks anyway for your time!