# Document.write can be a form of eval

Tags: javascript

```
function x(y){document.write('<script src="'+y+'" type="text/javascript"></script>')
```

Document.write can be a form of eval.

Got this message from jshint any idea how can solve the problem?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15048239/798677

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Don't use `document.write`.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = y;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: @MildFuzz This code can be used at any time, not just while the page is loading.

Comment: You must be using `document.write` elsewhere then.

Comment: Okay, so it has increased versatility, but in security terms, both are the same, right? Both could lead to the execution of malicious code.

Comment: @MildFuzz True, from a security perspective, however that depends on where `y` comes from exactly.

Comment: It depends just as much for either solution. I guess my point is that, linting and versatility aside, there is nothing "wrong" with how the OP has done it.