# How to print hollow inverted star pattern in JavaScript in a good way?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

i have tried the code below, but it just show an inverted pyramid with no hollow. it also has an error unknown

```js
var row = 5
for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp;");
  } {
    for (j = 1; j <= (row * 2 - (2 * i - 1)); j++) {
      if (i == 1 || j == 1 || j == (row * 2 - (2 * i - 1))) {
        document.write("*");
      } else {
        document.write("&nbsp;");
      }
    }
  }
  document.write("<br/>")
}
```

i expected a hollow inverted star pattern

Comment: *it also has an error* Can you share what the error message is?

Comment: Not getting into logic, every character has its own width. So a space and a asterisk will not occupy same space. Try adding following style: `body { font-family: monospace }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help. if you think the shape is not correct.

```js
var row = 5
for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  } {
    for (j = 1; j <= (row * 2 - (2 * i - 1)); j++) {
      if (i == 1 || j == 1 || j == (row * 2 - (2 * i - 1))) {
        document.write("*");
      } else {
        document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
      }
    }
  }
  document.write("<br/>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `document.write()` because document.write shows error like `document.write can be a form of eval` and it is bad practice as mentioned in link [document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048194/why-am-i-receiving-this-jsfiddle-error-document-write-can-be-a-form-of-eval)

HTML can be :

```
<div id="divid">
</div>
```

You can write javascript code as follows:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("divid");
var content = document.createTextNode('\u00A0');
theDiv.appendChild(content);
var content = "";
var row = 5
for (i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
   var content = document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0');
   theDiv.appendChild(content);
  } 
    for (j = 1; j <= (row * 2 - (2 * i - 1)); j++) {
      if (i == 1 || j == 1 || j == (row * 2 - (2*i - 1))) {
         var content = document.createTextNode("*");
         theDiv.appendChild(content);
      } else {
        var content = document.createTextNode('\u00A0\u00A0');
        theDiv.appendChild(content);
      }
    }

     var content = document.createElement("br");
     theDiv.appendChild(content);
  }
```

Here is the link of jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpmv7nxk/)