# How to sum of each array combination using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to Find the Sum of each array combination & required each combination in each line.
How to get the sum of each combination and display it in each line with innerHTML ?

**EDIT**

For each number in the range of 0 to 9999, get the sum of their digits: ex. `123 => 1 + 2 + 3 = 6`

Display each line with a zero padded 4 digit index number, an equal sign, and the sum: ex. `0123 = 6`

```js
var arraysToCombine = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];
var getAllCombinations = function(arraysToCombine) {
  var divisors = [];
  for (var i = arraysToCombine.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    divisors[i] = divisors[i + 1] ? divisors[i + 1] * arraysToCombine[i + 1].length : 1;

  }

  function getPermutation(n, arraysToCombine) {
    var result = [],
      curArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < arraysToCombine.length; i++) {
      curArray = arraysToCombine[i];
      result.push(curArray[Math.floor(n / divisors[i]) % curArray.length]);
    }
    return result;
  }
  var numPerms = arraysToCombine[0].length;
  for (var i = 1; i < arraysToCombine.length; i++) {
    numPerms *= arraysToCombine[i].length;
  }
  var combinations = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numPerms; i++) {
    combinations.push(getPermutation(i, arraysToCombine));
  }
  return combinations;
}
document.write(getAllCombinations(arraysToCombine));
```

Comment: *"...& required each combination in each line."* what? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OP Objective

For each number in the range of 0 to 9999, get the sum of their digits:

```
123 => 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
```

Display each line with a zero padded 4 digit index number, an equal sign, and the sum:

```
0123 = 6
```

**Dealing with the DOM**

The request to use `.innerHTML` is respectfully ignored. Rendering each line onto the DOM separately is too slow. Instead we will create a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) which isn't in the DOM, then add a `<div>` with a line of text for each sum. Once all 10,000 lines have been added to the fragment, we just add the fragment to `<body>`. That procedure will cost exactly one single DOM operation and one reflow instead of 10,000 DOM operations and reflows. For details on performance, here's an [article](https://johnresig.com/blog/dom-documentfragments/) written by the creator of jQuery.

### Solution

For reasons previously mentioned, create a document fragment.

```
let frag = new DocumentFragment
```

Next, create an array of numbers in the range of 0 to 9999 (10,000 numbers!)

```
const XxM = [...new Array(10000)].map((_, i) => i);
// [1, 2, 3, ...9999]
```

After that, iterate through each number with `.flatMap()`

```
const sums = XxM.flatMap(four => [...])
```

For each number in `XxM` convert it into a string, then split it into an array of chars.

```
four.toString().split('')
// 456 => "456" => ["4", "5", "6"]
```

Next, each sub-array of strings will be coerced back into a sub-array of numbers (ie `(+num)`) and the sum of all numbers will be returned by [`.reduce()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363105/2813224)

```
.reduce((sum, num) => sum + (+num), 0)
/* ["4", "5", "6"] =>  0  + (+"4" => 4)
                   =>  4  + (+"5" => 5)
                   =>  9  + (+"6" => 6)
                   <=  15
 */
```

Afterwards, the array of `sums` must be displayed. For each number of `sums` will be iterated by `.forEach()` since we don't need any values returned. On each iteration, make a `<div>`.

```
sums.forEach((sum, idx) => {
  let item = document.createElement('DIV');
```

Then make a text line consisting of an index number patterned like so: `0001, 0002, 0003, ...9999` an equals sign: `=`, and the `sum`. Next insert the text line into the new `<div>`.

```
   item.textContent = `${idx.toString().padStart(4, '0')} = ${sum}`;
```

Then add the `<div>` to the document fragment and repeat for 9,999 more times, and then add the fragment to the `<body>` only once.

```
   frag.appendChild(item); // 10,000 times!
});
document.body.appendChild(frag); // ONCE!
```

**Reminder:** Do not try to render each line into DOM. My first attempt to do so was so slow the browser prompted me to wait or cancel 4 times! For big operations such as this, using a document fragment as I have just demonstrated makes speed issues with the DOM trivial. Also, do not use [`document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048239/2813224)

```js
let frag = new DocumentFragment();
const XxM = [...new Array(10000)].map((_, i) => i);
const sums = XxM.flatMap(four => [four.toString().split('').reduce((sum, num) => sum + (+num), 0)]);
sums.forEach((sum, idx) => {
  let item = document.createElement('DIV');
  item.textContent = `${idx.toString().padStart(4, '0')} = ${sum}`;
  frag.appendChild(item);
});
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: If you run my code with console.log(getAllCombinations(arraysToCombine));  instead of document.write(getAllCombinations(arraysToCombine));  you will get each 4 digit combinations of 4 arrays, e.g. 0000, 0001, 0012.... we will get  around 10000 total numbers. I wanted to display those each combination of 4 digit in each line with <br/>
and to get the sum of each combination of 4 digit . 
e.g. results should display in screen as below 4 digit & sum of that 4 digit 
0000 = 0 
0001 = 1
..........
9999 = 36

Comment:  Ok, you should replace your code with mine it's  less verbose.